# VB script + change the first value of the first param in txt file

Tags: vbscript

how to replace only the first value of MODE parameter 
in the bash script from "ON" to "OFF" by VB script?

the bash script location:  C:\folder_scripts\script.bash

THX

Yael

the bash script (txt file):

```
#!/bin/bash

MODE=ON


if [[ $MODE = ON ]]

then

 echo "the machine is on line"

elif  [[ $MODE = OFF ]]

 echo "the machine is OFF line"

fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace has a Count and Start argument, setting Count to 1 will replace the first occurance:

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sf = "C:\folder_scripts\script.bash"

Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(sf, 1) ''1=for reading
s = f.ReadAll
s = Replace(s, "MODE=On", "MODE=Off",1,1)
f.Close
Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(sf, 2) ''2=ForWriting
f.Write s
f.Close
```

If the text could vary, for example, in the number of spaces between MODE and equals sign, you can read the text line by line (s=f.ReadLine) until you find the first line in which MODE occurs.